# How to get bean properties from security-context.xml and use them in java class?

Tags: xml, spring, security, ldap

I need to pass the properties of my bean in the security-context.xml and use it in the LDAP server configurations, passing only the variable and not writing the configuration data directly, so only the variables need to be changed from the security context. Xml in case of modifications.

This is my security-context bean

```
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.tilab.ngasp.policy.PolicyManager">
    <beans:property name="UrlLDAP" value="ldap://localhost:389" />
    <beans:property name="Principal" value="cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" />
    <beans:property name="Credential" value="secret" />
    <beans:property name="InitialContext" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

And this is the part of java class when i have to configure the LDAP server without insert configuration informations but only pass the variables with beans property

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public NgaspUsers findUser(String user)
{
    NgaspUsers utente = null;       

    Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
```

I want a DLAP Config like this :

```
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,StringVariableWithContextFactory);
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, StringVariableWithLdapUrl);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, StringVariableWithRootInformation);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,StringVariableWithPassword);
```

I'm using Spring Security, Eclipse and Tomcat 6.0.

Thank's all, hope this informations is sufficient for helping me!

---  EDIT FOR  Messaoud GUERNOUTI

I tried using your last method to also use the external class but I have this error in env.put (Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, myUserDetailsService.getInitialContext ());

Error : **The method getInitialContext() is undefined for the type PolicyManager**

PolicyManager.java now is so right now :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myUserDetailsService")
PolicyManager myUserDetailsService;
public NgaspUsers findUser(String user)
{
    NgaspUsers utente = null;       

    Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,myUserDetailsService.getInitialContext()); 
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
```

I just tried the first "put" but I already have this problem, did I correctly insert the annotations in the right place or is there any other problem?

EDIT 2 :

Basics Getters and setters like this or need to extract the value in xml file?

```
public String InitialContext1;
public String Credential1;
public String UrlLDAP1;
public String Principal1;


public String getInitialContext1() {
    return InitialContext1;
}

public void setInitialContext1(String initialContext) {
    InitialContext1 = initialContext;
}

public String getCredential1() {
    return Credential1;
}

public void setCredential1(String credential) {
    Credential1 = credential;
}

public String getUrlLDAP1() {
    return UrlLDAP1;
}

public void setUrlLDAP1(String urlLDAP) {
    UrlLDAP1 = urlLDAP;
}

public String getPrincipal1() {
    return Principal1;
}

public void setPrincipal1(String principal) {
    Principal1 = principal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using the Spring Security LDAP default Provider for authentification :

```
<sec:authentication-manager>
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:389/cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" />
        <property name="userDn" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
        <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <constructor-arg value="" />
                <property name="defaultRole" value="ROLE_USER"/>
                <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
                <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

if you want to use your own class, you can add

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myUserDetailsService") 
PolicyManager myUserDetailsService;
```

then access all properties by getter by example :

```
Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,myUserDetailsService.getInitialContext());
```

you must generate `getter` & `setter` for all attributes on class `PolicyManager`

Comment: If i want to use this method, i have to use only security-context and no more a external java class like my actual config?

Comment: Yes you can use only security-context no need to extrenal class

Comment: Unfortunately my workgroup prefers to work with an external class...Can you help me with my situation? I really can't find a good method to "capture" the beans value and insert into external connection manager class

Comment: See my edit in my main question, i have that problem

Comment: You can use Basics getter/setter